# Excel, simple reverse equation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'd like the Data that is in (A1:A:5) to be displayed in (B1:B5) in reverse order. The bottom one in A5 to appear in B1 and so on. Please and thanks

Comment: Take a look here and see if this helps.  It shows first how to do it through GUI, but then how to do it through VBA (scroll down a little): http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/excel-quick-tips-flip-cells-switch-rows-columns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,6-ROW())
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put this one formula in B1 and copy/drag down:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,A:A),0),IFERROR(MATCH("ZZZ",A:A),0)))),ROW(1:1)))
```

It is dynamic and does not care how many values are in A, it will resize as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Using VBA:**

```
Sub FlipColumns()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    xTitleId = "Tools4Excel"

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Arr = WorkRng.Formula

    For j = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
        k = UBound(Arr, 1)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1) / 2
            xTemp = Arr(i, j)
            Arr(i, j) = Arr(k, j)
            Arr(k, j) = xTemp
            k = k - 1
        Next
    Next
    WorkRng.Formula = Arr
End Sub
```

When you execute this macro, it will ask you which column range you want to rewrite in the inverse order.

---

**Using Formulas:**

You can use [`OFFSET()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66), [`COUNTA()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) and [`ROW()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) to achieve this.

Example of formulas:

```
cell B1    =OFFSET($A$1;COUNTA(A:A)-ROW(A1);0)
cell B2    =OFFSET($A$1;COUNTA(A:A)-ROW(A2);0)
cell B3    =OFFSET($A$1;COUNTA(A:A)-ROW(A3);0)
cell B4    =OFFSET($A$1;COUNTA(A:A)-ROW(A4);0)
cell B5    =OFFSET($A$1;COUNTA(A:A)-ROW(A5);0)
```

Just put `=OFFSET($A$1;COUNTA(A:A)-ROW(A1);0)` at cell b2 and drag down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ReverseRange()

For i = 1 To 5
    Range("b" & i).Value = Range("a5").Offset(0 - (i - 1), 0).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

with VBA

```
Range("B1:B5").Value = Application.Transpose(Split(StrReverse(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A5").Value), "|")), "|"))
```